# Python Unbound Method TypeError

Tags: python, methods, tkinter

The method `get_pos` is supposed to grab what the user inputs in the entry. When `get_pos` is executed, it returns with:

> TypeError: unbound method get_pos() must be called with app instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

**Code:**

```
class app(object):
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.functionframe=FunctionFrame(root, self)
            self.functionframe.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    def get_pos(self):
        self.functionframe.input(self)
class FunctionFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master,parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,master,bg="grey90")
        self.entry = Entry(self,width=15)
        self.entry.pack
    def input(self):
        self.input = self.entry.get()
        return self.input
```

Comment: Where's the code for the entry method?

Comment: Still not enough information here. Where are you actually calling get_pos()?

Comment: get_pos() is binded to a button and I have tested that all the binds work fine

Comment: One of the problems here is the last method is assigning an attribute with the same name as the method (input), thus making the method disappear. Future references to functionframe.input will get whatever self.entry.get() returned.

Answer (score 47):

You reported this error:

> TypeError: unbound method get_pos() must be called with app instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

What this means in layman's terms is you're doing something like this:

```
class app(object):
    def get_pos(self):
        ...
...
app.get_pos()
```

What you need to do instead is something like this:

```
the_app = app()  # create instance of class 'app'
the_app.get_pos() # call get_pos on the instance
```

It's hard to get any more specific than this because you didn't show us the actual code that is causing the errors.

Comment: As of Python 3.0:

`The concept of “unbound methods” has been removed from the language. 
When referencing a method as a class attribute, you now get a plain function object.`

So this example is valid python 3.X code, since there are no "unbound methods" just functions attached to class objects.

Comment: Yup. I'm here because I'm backporting my codebase to 2.7.

Answer (score 16):

I've run into this error when forgetting to add parentheses to the class name when constructing an instance of the class:

from my.package import MyClass

```
# wrong
instance = MyClass

instance.someMethod() # tries to call MyClass.someMethod()

# right
instance = MyClass()


instance.someMethod()
```

Answer (score 3):

My crystal ball tells me that you are binding `app.get_pos` to a button using the class `app` (which really should be called `App`) instead of creating an instance `app_instance = app` and using `app_instance.get_pos`.

Of course as others have pointed out there are so many other issues with the code you did post it is a bit hard to guess at the mistakes in the code you didn't post.

Comment: I tried to restructure my own code when I posted this because the original would take far too long to debug about 200 lines plus for the application i'm making.

Comment: The point is that when you restructured it you also removed the relevant parts that would let people actually be able to tell you what the problem is.